# How to continue to show a please wait page during a page reload using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 and I have to disable all elements on a page with forms, selects, and links while displaying a please wait animation.

I found a free animation at [Ajaxload](http://ajaxload.info/) and was using `$('.gif').show();` to display it, waiting until some javascript functions complete and then calling `$('.gif').hide();`

However, I ran into something I wasn't expecting.  When the user selects a new item in the dropdown the loading gif animation displays, but shortly thereafter, in a nested javascript functions associated with the dropdown, it calls for a page refresh with new data from a database call and removes my animation before I can call the hide function.

So my question is, is it possible to display an animation that will display in the jsp and then continue until the reload is complete?

I was using something like this to disable the link click events:

```
 $("a").click(function(event) {
   // add some conditional logic here if animation is running then
    event.preventDefault(); ...
```

So, is there a better way to globally disable all the elements on the page, preventing a click event or a change event on the select dropdown?

**Aftermath:**

I used the suggestion of Archer for the background div, the answer from Jai, along with this blog article: [jQuery page loading delay](http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-page-loading-delay.html), this article on using a [modal window with an animation](http://blog.lavgupta.com/2011/12/jquery-modal-waiting-dialog.html) and came up with a custom solution that fit exactly what I needed.

Thanks for the help from everyone, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: The easiest way I've found is to cover the page with a div so you can't use anything underneath it.  Would you consider a modal dialog with the loading animation in it?  There's plenty (jQueryUI being very simple to use).

Comment: I looked at the modal dialog first and I've used other jQuery UI widgets before, so I'll check that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be using `doc ready` and `window load` together this way:

```
$(function(){
   $('.gif').show();
   $(window).load(function(){
      $('.gif').hide();
      $('#wrapper').show();
   });
});
```

initially the `wrapper div needs to be hidden`, when window fully gets loaded `show the wrapper` and `hide the gif`.